@event.listens_for() didnt work with endpoint
"I need to delete cache by key, which I could get from a remote object endpoint of FastAPI. In the documentation, I read that I can use event.listens_for with a parameter to track the table from which I delete and the parameter 'after_delete'. But when I use this endpoint, it doesn't even start and doesn't output any logs of its body. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?"
@router.delete("/{id}", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def delete_translate(id: int, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
    async with TranslateDao(session) as dao:
        return await dao.delete_item(id)
    

    #### Events ####
@event.listens_for(TranslateLanguageModel, 'after_delete')
async def receive_after_delete(mapper, connection, target):
    language_id = target.language_id
    print(f'delete_translate-{language_id}')
    cache.clear(f'delete_translate-{language_id}')



async def delete_item(self, item_id: int) -> bool:
        item = await self.get_item_by_id(item_id)
        if not item:
            return False
        try:
            await self.session.execute(delete(self.model).where(self.model.id == item_id))
            await self.session.flush()
        except SQLAlchemyError as exc:
            logger.error(exc.args)
            raise
        return True




I have already tried to get the language_id, which is necessary to delete the cache key via returning, but it breaks my dao logic on other routes

According to the docs for after_delete: "this event only applies to the session flush operation and does not apply to the ORM DML operations" and "use SessionEvents.do_orm_execute()." In other words, "after_delete" is used with session.delete(model) and 'do_orm_execute' is is used with session.execute(delete(model)).

its makes a sense, thx
